# How to search with the Contains method in a List if there are multiple columns of data?

Tags: c#, computer-science

Good afternoon, there is a List with several columns of data, here is an example

```cs
public static List<(double date, double profit)> data_good_proffit = 
  new List<(double date, double profit)>();
```

how to write to search using the Contains method in the Profit column?

```
data_good_proffit.Contains();
```

so writes an error

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: I suspect this is an XY problem, with the OP not understanding what a double is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Contain` will do if you want to find out the entire tuple, e.g.

```
// Do we have date == 5.0 and profit == 7.1?
bool result = data_good_proffit.Contains((5.0, 7.1));
```

If you want to check for `profit` only and ignore the `date` try to query with a help of Linq:

```
using System.Linq;

...

// Do we have any item with profit == 7.1?
bool result = data_good_proffit.Any(item => item.profit == 7.1);
```

please, not that you have a list of tuples, with no separate columns existing.